# React. Creating a function that returns html

Tags: javascript, html, function, reactjs, return

I recently started working with react and I am facing a bit of an issue.

Currently I have the following piece of code

```
<div className="col-md-4"><h4>ML</h4>
{
    game.lines.map(function (lineGroup) {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    {lineGroup.Pay}
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{getLineInfo(lineGroup.HomeInfo)}</strong>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{getLineInfo(lineGroup.Score)}</strong>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{getLineInfo(lineGroup.AwayInfo)}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

This sits in my `render()` function.

However I have this exact same piece of code copy/pasted 5 more times with only minor changes. 
I wish to extract it to a function, but I am not sure how would I do this.

Where should I place the function ? -Inside the render() method?

What should I return from it? - A string that contains the html and variables in {} placeholders?

Do I simply call it within the html?

Comment: Is it ***exactly*** the same, just repeated 5 times?

Comment: No, the contents of the seconds <strong> tag change.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create function like this :

```
function gameLines(game) {
    return game.lines.map(function (lineGroup) {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    {lineGroup.Pay}
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{this.getLineInfo(lineGroup.HomeInfo)}</strong>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{this.getLineInfo(lineGroup.Score)}</strong>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <strong>{this.getLineInfo(lineGroup.AwayInfo)}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Use like this :

```
<div className="col-md-4"><h4>ML</h4>
    { this.gameLines(game) }
</div>
```

Dont forget to bind the functions

```
constructor() {
    ...
    this.gameLines = this.gameLines.bind(this);
    this.getLineInfo = this.getLineInfo.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: How is it possible to return HTML code from a JavaScript function? This question was asked elsewhere in 2017 and there is no answer yet. Anyone understand this?

Comment: It is apparently a new language called JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html . I imagine it only works with react.