# How to pass a value to for( htmlFor ) attribute in checkbox component in react-bootstrap?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, wcag2.0

I am maintaining **WCAG2.0** 'AA' standards on a project in which i need to provide a value to **for** attribute in checkbox component in react-bootstrap but could not find a proper solution.

**Code::**
what i am writing jsx

```
<Checkbox checked={ props.item.selected || false }
onChange={() => {}}>
    <div className="label-text"></div>
</Checkbox>
```

what i looks like in html:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label title="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on">
        <div class="label-text"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

looking for sort of html :

```
<label **for="boxa"**>birds</label>
<input **id="boxa"** type="checkbox" name="mytext" />
```

Comment: The understanding for your code is not quite clear. Please add more details and what I think is you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956250/7528968

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look over the source code of the component from [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap), but **TLDR**: they **don't provide an option** to add a `for` attribute on a `Checkbox` component. There's even an eslint disable *[for](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/3e5a8d510b5acdacee165dbd60783fa65b615c0e/src/Checkbox.js#L1)* it.

Here's the [source](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/3e5a8d510b5acdacee165dbd60783fa65b615c0e/src/Checkbox.js#L80) of the label that accompanies the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If this is reactstrap try this:

```
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
```

```
<Form>
  <FormGroup>
    <Input type="checkboxId" />
    <Label htmlFor="checkboxId">
      Some input
    </Label>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```