# Return component from within a react method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get React to return a component from within a method in another component.  So far I have:

```
export class Projects extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.loadProjects = this.loadProjects.bind(this);
    }

    loadProjects() {
        var userProjectsRef = dbroot.child("users").child(this.props.user.uid).child("projects").ref;
        userProjectsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            var id = snapshot.val();
            return (
                <ProjectsRow projectId={id} />
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header bg-dark text-light align-center">
                    </div>
                    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush align-left">
                        {this.loadProjects()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <AddProjectModal user={this.props.user} />
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

I am not sure why the return statement in the loadProjects method is not working.  It can return a console.log statement in the same place, however.  I also referenced this stack overflow question: [React. Creating a function that returns html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955880/react-creating-a-function-that-returns-html)
Any Ideas?

Comment: It looks as though you have an async callback that returns `<ProjectsRow>`.  This won't return in the same context.

Comment: Hi Zach, your return is not working without errors ? As you are new to react I advise you managing component on event basis without state is an anti-pattern in react.

Answer (score 0):

Store your project data in the [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) and you can update the state when a project is added. This way, you can `.map()` the state in the render function which React will automatically keep calling as you add projects.

```
export class Projects extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // set initial empty state
        this.state = {
          projects : []
        };
    }

    // do the state manipulation after the component has mounted
    componentDidMount() {
        var userProjectsRef = dbroot.child("users").child(this.props.user.uid).child("projects").ref;
        userProjectsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            var id = snapshot.val();
            const newProject = {id :id};

            // update the state and add the new project
            this.setState((prevState) => ({
              ...prevState, // not needed in this trivial example but would be needed if the state stored other things because setState overwrites the whole state
              projects : [...prevState.projects, newProject] // the updated project is array is the existing array with the new one appended
            }));
        }.bind(this)); // bind this context because the function creates its own this context (or switch to an arrow function)
    }

    // map this.state.projects to <ProjectsRow> components
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header bg-dark text-light align-center">
                    </div>
                    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush align-left">
                        {this.state.projects.map((project, index) => <ProjectsRow key={index} projectId={project.id} />)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <AddProjectModal user={this.props.user} />
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```