# Error: "x" is read-only: Trying to render a HTML variable element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a cart and I have to dynamically render the cart Qty in a  tag.

To do this I have a function `cartQtySelectRender` that `for loops` the `this.state.cartItemsQty` and creates a string html tag variable like so...

```
  cartQtySelectRender() {
    const cartQty = this.state.cartItemsQty;
    const qtySelectElement = "<select>";
    if (cartQty > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= cartQty; i++) {
        qtySelectElement += `<option> ${i} </option>`;
      }
      return (qtySelectElement += "</select>");
    } else {
      qtySelectElement += "<option>0</option>";
      return qtySelectElement;
    }
  }
```

I render the returned value `qtySelectElement` in the render method `--->`

```
  render() {


    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Cart </h1>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
              # code...
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.cartItems.map(itemObj => (
              <tr key={itemObj.item.id}>
                <td>{itemObj.item.name}</td>
                <td>{itemObj.item.productDesc}</td>
                <td>
                  <select>{this.cartQtySelectRender()}</select> <<----
                </td>
                <td>{itemObj.item.productPrice}</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

> ```
> Error: "qtySelectElement" is read-only
>
>  24 | const qtySelectElement = "<select>";
>   25 | if (cartQty > 0) {
>   26 |   for (let i = 0; i <= cartQty; i++) {
> > 27 |     qtySelectElement += `<option> ${i} </option>`;
>      | ^  28 |   }
>   29 |   return (qtySelectElement += "</select>");
>   30 | } else {
> ```

Comment: you cant change the value of const one assigned..i guess that is your problem..change `const qtySelectElement` to `let qtySelectElement` and try

Comment: OMG! That was it changed it to var. But now it just strings out as a string in the dom... not as a html tag. any ideas? please

Comment: of course..you are returning a string..check out this linkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955880/react-creating-a-function-that-returns-html

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a string, but create JSX like below

```
cartQtySelectRender() {
    const cartQty = this.state.cartItemsQty;
    return (
       <select> 
          <option value="0" >0</option>
          {
            for(let i=1; i<= cartQty; i++)
            { <option key={i} value={i}> {i} </option> } 
          }
       </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: question: In react is it allowed to use the for/if loop in the render() method? if so, i don't have to encapsulate this login in a function (?)..