# How to use return function to display any element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, return

I've seen functions written like this to display elements. I want to just make the

hello world

appear on the webpage. But it doesn't work for me. Using this method will make my application infinitely easier to write instead of constantly rewriting .innerhtml across every element.

```
function returnTest(){
  
  console.log("function is running");

  return `<p> hello world </p>`;
  }

$(returnTest);
```

Comment: Try this one https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to use this function and can even pass parameters to change the text inside

The basic way is this:-

```
function returnTest(val){
   return `<p> ${val} </p>`;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#temp").html(returnTest("Hello world!"));
});
```

You can also create Jquery Functions though I have used the one you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I create a jsfiddle for you to check on https://jsfiddle.net/renzuii/rw714u5x/

```
function returnTest(){
  console.log("function is running");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "hello world";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

returnTest();
```

You must use createElement first then append it on the body.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be inserted somewhere.

```
$('body').append(returnTest);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I originally went with and it worked very well. In the end though append did not work fully for my application as i had to replace the text a few times. append just attached it so it was growing and growing. But I will use this for future applications and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done in Reactjs. You can not do that using jquery. If you want to do in jquery then you have to use what other answers have shown.

```
<div className="col-md-1">
    { this.returnTest }
</div>
```

Dont forget to bind the function. It will look like below.

```
constructor() {
    this.returnTest = this.returnTest .bind(this);
}
```

You can also refer below link. shows same if you want to do this.
[React. Creating a function that returns html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955880/react-creating-a-function-that-returns-html)